# Can Java Logger do this: logger.fine("foo = " + bar)?

Tags: debugging, logging, ejb-3.0

I am trying to debug the value of an object in EJB
If I do `logger.fine("foo")`, then I can see `foo`, but if I do `logger.fine("foo = " + bar)` then i cant see anything. So how do I debug in EJB? I am using netbean 6.8 btw

Comment: Is `bar`'s `toString()` method throwing an exception?

Comment: Thank you, I catch `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure bar.toString() is not throwing some runtime exception? Otherwise it should work.

Try a try...catch block around it to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, I catch `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Harry You don't need to allow the NullPointerException just so you can catch it; just check for null ahead of time. `logger.fine("foo = " + (bar == null ? "null" : bar))`

Comment: Thanks. What I mean before is since I catch `NullPointerException` I figure out what wrong with my code. It not because Java Logger cant print variable, it because my variable is `null`. Once I know that, then I start the tracing. It is fixed now. Thank you very much